# Why is my img element overriding the background color of my header element?

Tags: html, css, header, position

I've create a header to track as I scroll down my webpage, but my `img` element overrides the black background color I've set for the `header` element (see image below). I'm not sure what the issue is, but I'd like my header to have a black background and not be transparent as I scroll.

```
    <header class="fixed top-0 w-full bg-black">
    <div class="sm:flex sm:justify-between">
    <div class="flex items-center justify-between px-2 py-2">
      <div>
        <a class="text-white font-bold text-xl" href="#"
        >Corner Hair Salon</a>
      </div>
      <div class="sm:hidden">
        <button type="button" class="block" onclick="myFunction()">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 fill-current text-white"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M3.75 6.75h16.5M3.75 12h16.5m-16.5 5.25h16.5"/></svg>
       </button>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-white px-1 pb-1 hidden sm:flex sm:items-center sm:pb-0" id="myLinks">
        <a href="#" class="block px-1 rounded hover:bg-gray-400">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="#" class="mt-1 block px-1 rounded hover:bg-gray-400 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-2">Book an Appointment</a>
        <a href="#" class="mt-1 block px-1 rounded hover:bg-gray-400 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-2">Employee Sign-In</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex flex-col space-y-1">
      <div class="bg-white w-full" style="height: 3px"></div>
      <div class="bg-white w-full" style="height: 2px"></div>
      <div class="bg-white w-full" style="height: 1px"></div>
    </div>
  </header>

    <div class="relative justify-center overflow-hidden" style="height: 600px">
      <img
        src="../img/salon.jpg"
        alt="Salon"
        class="blur-xs opacity-25 w-full h-full object-cover backdrop-blur-md hover:scale-125 transition duration-500 cursor-pointer"
      />
      <div
        class="flex flex-col items-center absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2"
      >
        <h1 class="text-white text-xl sm:text-4xl lg:text-6xl">
          Corner Hair Salon
        </h1>
        <p class="text-white text-xl sm:text-2xl lg:text-4xl">El Paso, TX</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I saw the image but I'm still not sure I understand the problem... Is the problem that the image is covering the background?

Comment: Hi Ortund - that's correct. The div element containing the image and h1 is covering the background of my header, so my content looks weird as I scroll. I've attached new images to better show the problem. Ultimately, I'd like my header (and its black background) to be the foremost element on the screen, covering other content as I scroll (similar to image 3). Thank you!